# AppDelegate object returns nil when directory path is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

//my button action method

```
-(IBAction)signupBtn
{
  [appDelegate.database executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO signUp (username,email, password, cnfpassword) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ", userName.text,emailName.text,passWord.text,cnfpassWord.text];

  NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",userName.text);    // works fine
  NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",emailName.text);
  NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",passWord.text);
  NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",cnfpassWord.text);
  NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",appDelegate.docsDir); // returns nil...my problem
}
```

//My app delegate.m class`

```
#import "ViewController3.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"


@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize dirPaths,docsDir,database;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //get the directory
    dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];

    database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

    [database open];
    [database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE users (username text primary key, email text, password text, cnfpassword text) " ];

    NSLog(@"docsDir : %@",docsDir);

    return YES;
}
```

//my apdelegate.h class file includes

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong,nonatomic) FMDatabase *database;

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray *dirPaths;

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *docsDir;
```

Comment: How you created appDelegate object in the view controller where you places signup method ?

Comment: I have declared AppDelegate object in viewcontroller.h file like AppDelegate *appDelegate. The reason behind this is because I have defined database directory paths and table creation query inside AppDelegate.m

Comment: Where and how did you initialise that object ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the exact problem?

Comment: The code you have for getting the path to save the sqlite to is fine, I tested it in a sample app and it returns valid paths to save to.

Answer (score -2):

Array `dirPaths` returns nil because it is not initialised. So, please initialise it first before using.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Initialise Array
    dirPaths = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    //get the directory
    // YOUR CODE
    return YES;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Please check edited code. Initialise if you have not initialise AppDelegate's object.

Thanks.

Comment: `dirPaths` is already assigned something because your sending the result from calling `NSNSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` into it.

Comment: First..I haven't initialised the app delegate's object..but even after doing so..I

Comment: Unrecognised selector sent to instance. Actually I was unable to call the database class object from the app delegate. For that I created a macro in my app delegate.h like #define APP_DELEGATE ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

Comment: @AkashKR Is it crashing app ??

Comment: Yes it was..but now my problem has been solved. Actually I need to declare the AppDelegate initialisation.

Comment: Ok. So is your question solved which is posted ? or still having issue ?